# PHP Convert Minutes+Seconds to Seconds

Tags: php, time

Currently, I have the following time format like the following:

```
0m12.345s
2m34.567s
```

I put them in variable `$time`. How do I convert the variable to seconds only in PHP, like `12.345` for the first one, and `154.567` for the second one?

Comment: you'd first parse the amount of minutes and amount of seconds to separate variables, then multiple minutes by 60 and finish with adding the numbers together.

Comment: does the time will have m AND s in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $time="2m34.567s";
    $split=explode('m',$time);
//   print_r($split[0]);
    $split2=explode('s',$split[1]);

$sec= seconds_from_time($split[0])+$split2[0];
echo $sec;
function seconds_from_time($time) {

        return $time*60;
    }

?>
```

Demo here http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gdf-3tj

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this,

```
//Exploding time string on 'm' this way we have an array 
//with minutes at the 0 index and seconds at the 1 index
//substr function is used to remove the last s from your initial time string
$time_array=explode('m', substr($time, 0, -1));
//Calculating 
$time=($time_array[0]*60)+$time_array[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanly parse your strictly formatted string into its relevant parts as an integer type value (`%d`) and a float type value (`%f`), then increase the `$seconds` variable by the `$minutes` value multiplied by `60`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UIWZf))

```
$tests = ['0m12.345s', '2m34.567s'];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    sscanf($test, '%dm%f', $minutes, $seconds);
    $seconds += $minutes * 60;
    echo $seconds . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
12.345
154.567
```