# Convert years.months formatted string to months in PHP

Tags: php, time, text-parsing, units-of-measurement, delimited

Unfortunately, I have data from a client in an unusual format. I expected years and months in separate columns, but instead, it comes as a dot-delimited string: `[years].[months]`.

I have imported this data into MySql Database and now requires to convert `years.months` to `months` on which I am going to set some action further.

So I want to convert **years (with months after the decimal)** to **months** only in PHP.

Test cases:

- `1.2` (1 year, 2 months) to `14`

> 

- `1.0` (1 year, 0 months) to `12`

I have written the below code that may be having issues so I want to correct it.

```
$yearwithdecimal = "1.2";
$yearwithdecimal = (float)$yearwithdecimal;
if (is_float($yearwithdecimal)) {
    $yearsArray = explode(".",$yearwithdecimal);
    $year_months = $yearsArray[0]*12;
    $more_months = $yearsArray[1];
    $total_months = $year_months + $more_months;
}else{
    $total_months = $yearwithdecimal*12;
}
echo $total_months; die;
// Output is 14
```

Comment: How do you represent 1 year and 11 months? 1.11?

Comment: Value is already coming from the database like this

Comment: 1.5 years are 17 months from that code?

Comment: @brombeer Yes it will output like this

Comment: This question seems more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but you still need to inform of what you really want to improve?

Comment: @AmitGupta So, 1.10 will be 1 year and 10 months and 1.12 will be 2 years, correct?

Comment: @nice_dev Yes 1.10 will be 1 year and 10 months but 1.12 will never come as it will come like 2.0 for 2 years

Comment: Client has a data like this that is imported to the Database

Comment: You can't distinguish between 1.10 and 1.1 if it's a float number.

Comment: @shingo So it means there is no solution to convert it; we may require to sort the data first like to separate years and months in separate columns

Comment: @AmitGupta Ok, is the data stored as a float or as a string in the database?

Comment: That's an odd way to use decimals imho. Do people anywhere actually use that "format"?

Comment: @nice_dev Data is in a string in database but I have converted it to float with (float)$yearwithdecimal;

Comment: @brombeer Yes some of the clients still use data like this and as a developer we need to accept data in any form.

Comment: You'll have to parse each part (years and months) separately I think, not as a single number, to get round the problem shingo pointed out

Comment: @AmitGupta Since it is stored as a string, it makes the problem far easier. The confusion came when we thought you had it as a float by default.

Comment: Topically relevant: [PHP Convert Minutes+Seconds to Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21952657/2943403) and [convert number of months to the number of years and months](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33377028/2943403)

Comment: Also topical: [Parse feet and inches formatted string and convert to inches as a floating point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897121/2943403)

Comment: @mickmackusa Please let me know why the question is closed and also get downvotes. I tried explaining it in the best possible manner.

Comment: My observations: initially, you did not precisely express your input values; early comments complained that the task was flawed because it relied on float-type values -- which would make the differentiation between `1.1` and `1.10` impossible.  Your [mcve] would be better if you demonstrated how your code incorrectly returns [`13` from `"1.10"`](https://3v4l.org/N1tKY). Also, I find your task to be VERY similar to other earlier pages -- this is the primary reason that I am holding back from voting to reopen. Overall, I might still uv the question if the [mcve] is improved. @amit

Comment: @shingo Please offer feedback to the asker about aspects of the question to improve since you were a close voter.

Comment: @mickmackusa I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your field the first part represents num of years and  the second part represents num of months.

Take the field as a string, then explode it by `.`

```
$yearwithdecimal = "1.2";
$months = 0;
if($yearwithdecimal){
    $parts = explode('.', $yearwithdecimal);
    $months = $parts[0]*12 + ($parts[1] ?? 0);
}
echo $months;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/VhOfV

Answer (score 3):

As demonstrated at [PHP Convert Minutes+Seconds to Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77408214/2943403), parse your formatted/delimited string into integer type variables, then increase the `$months` value by the `$years` value times `12`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bJJ1r))

```
$tests = ['1.2', '1.0', '2.11'];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    sscanf($test, '%d.%d', $years, $months);
    $months += $years * 12;
    echo $months . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
14
12
35
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $yearwithdecimal = "1.2";
$yearwithdecimal = (float)$yearwithdecimal;
if (is_float($yearwithdecimal)) {
    $yearsArray = explode(".",$yearwithdecimal);
    $year_months = $yearsArray[0]*12;

    $more_months = isset($yearsArray[1]) ? $yearsArray[1] : 0; 

     $total_months = $year_months + $more_months;
   }else{
        $total_months = $yearwithdecimal*12;
    }

     echo $total_months;
```

Comment: You're likely to get a more favourable response to your post if you take the time to explain your answer, including what you've done and why you expect that it solves the problem. Just dumping code is actually not very helpful most of the time. See also [answer]. In this case you might want to highlight why you think this is different/better than the various already-existing and quite similar answers. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

1. Split the increment value into 2 parts, $incYears and $incMonths
2. Convert the $incYears into months ($incYears * 12) and add the $incMonths
3. Add the month to the date

```
    function addDecimalYears($fromDate, $increment){
        $segments = explode(".", (string)$increment, 2);
        $incYears = isset($segments[0]) ? $segments[0] : 0;
        $incMonths = isset($segments[1]) ? $segments[1] : 0;

        $months = 12 * (int)$incYears;
        $months += (int)$incMonths;

        $fromDateTimestamp = strtotime($fromDate);
        return date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+" . $months . "month", $fromDateTimestamp));
    }

    echo addDecimalYears("2023-11-02", 1.0) . "\n";
    echo addDecimalYears("2023-11-02", 1.) . "\n";
    echo addDecimalYears("2023-11-02", .12) . "\n";
    echo addDecimalYears("2023-11-02", 1.6) . "\n";
    echo addDecimalYears("2023-11-02", .18) . "\n";
    echo addDecimalYears("2023-11-02", 0.6) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2024-11-02
2024-11-02
2024-11-02
2025-05-02
2025-05-02
2024-05-02
```

Comment: I don't see how this really answers the question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce the output that the OP wants

Answer (score -2):

```
$yearWithDecimal = 1.2;

$years = floor($yearWithDecimal);
$months = ($yearWithDecimal - $years) * 12;

$totalMonths = ($years * 12) + $months;

echo $totalMonths; // Output is 14.4
```

Comment: I've checked this and it seems to print 14.4?!

Comment: @NigelRen then why is there no downvote on this unexplained answer?

Comment: @mickmackusa it's up to me what I do with my votes - if it was posed as a 'why' I would have just ignored it - but to me - it sounds as though you are saying I've done something wrong.

Comment: It is a missed opportunity to curate.  This system affords its trusted users with the ability signal to future readers which portions of content are "good" and "not good".  This answer is clearly not good, but you have missed a chance to improve the experience of all future readers.  There is still time to do the right thing by the system.  When bad content is upvoted, it cannot be deleted by the community and wastes the time of future readers.  If you are not voting to delete bad content which is negatively scored, then I'll ask for that appropriate action as well.

Comment: @mickmackusa SO is not a system, people can curate in different ways - leaving a comment (IMHO) saying the answer is incorrect is better than any number of downvotes. You should act as you see fit but please give others the opportunity to do the same.

Comment: @webpress You'll get a more favourable response to your post if you take the time to explain your answer, including what you've done and why you expect that it solves the problem (and ideally demonstrating it with a demo, or listing the output you get from a few test cases). Just dumping code is actually not very helpful most of the time. See also [answer]. Also as already pointed out, this seems to produce incorrect results [at least in some cases](https://3v4l.org/SbGA1), so you might want to check that. Thanks.

Comment: @Nige when I got to this page, the unexplained and provably incorrect answer had a positive score. If that doesn't qualify for dv'ing in your book, what does? There are a paltry few regular users (with sufficient knowledge and ability) who have been granted the tools to curate. You are one of them. Yes, a whistleblowing comment is a step in the right direction, but bad, positively score content cannot be removed by volunteers. When you go that 1 small step further, other curators can proceed with vital curation.

Comment: @Nige The asker is requesting feedback about why the page is closed.  As a close voter, perhaps you can express what troubles you see with the asked question.